# Почему в слове выкосил проверяемая, а не чередующаяся гласная?

Tags: грамматика

[Здесь говорится, что в слове "выкосил" проверяемая, а не чередующаяся гласная.](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=14867)

> Укажите варианты ответов, в которых во всех словах одного ряда пропущена безударная чередующаяся гласная корня. Запишите номера ответов.
>
> 1. выр..стил, вык..сил (траву), пл..вчиха
>
> Приведём верное написание.
>
> 1. вырастил — ЧГ, выкосил (траву) — ПГ: ко́сит, пловчиха — ЧГ

Но, ведь, корень то `кос`, причем после нет `а`.
Было предположение, что проверяемыми гласными могут являться гласные, которые можно проверить, причем гласная в корня должна быть той же; например, слово касаться так не проверить. Однако это предположение опровергается словом изложение, которое можно проверить словом излОженный, но [там же](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=14867) говорится, что гласная - чередующаяся, а не проверяемая.
Я не знаю какого-то правила насчет корней с чередованием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словах *косить* и *касаться* разные корни, В слове *косить* корень *-кос-* с проверяемой гласной -**о**-, она в нём никогда с -**а**- не чередуется, потому её и можно проверить, поставив под ударение. А в слове *касаться* — корень *-кос- / -кас-* с чередующейся **о/а** — перед -а- в нём гласная **а**, а не перед -а- — гласная **о** (к**а**с**а**ться - к**о**снуться).

Там же по вашей же первой ссылке само правило-то и написано, «**Правило: Задание 9. Безударные гласные в корнях слов**», надо там на плюсик в квадратике после этих слов клацнуть, оно и развернётся. И в этом правиле пункт «**8.3.3.Чередование гласных а/о в корне**», подпункт «**2. Правописание корня зависит от последующей буквы**» с таблицей.

А насчёт слова «изложение» всё вообще просто, там ударением и проверять-то нечего, корень -**лаг**- чередуется с корнем -**лож**-, то есть перед **г** всегда **а**, а перед **ж** всегда **о**, и это тоже там, в той же самой таблице написано. Либо **лаг**, либо **лож** — нечего и проверять (есть, правда, одно исключение «полог»).

Comment: То есть, если есть слово с таким же значением и другим корнем(если корень лож, то с лаг, например), то гласная в корне с таким значением - чередующаяся, иначе - проверяемая или непроверяемая?

Comment: @World - Вот я совершенно не понял, что вы написали в своём комментарии после слов «То есть». Всё ведь логично: если есть _пара вариантов_ корня (лаг/лож, рос/раст, бер/бир, кас/кос), в которых гласная корня _зависит_ от своего окружения (от того, что идёт после неё, от того, стоит ли на ней ударение) или от значения (равн/ровн, мак/моч), то это **ЧГ**. Если же гласную корня под такие правила подвести нельзя и узнать эту гласную можно _**только**_ поставив её под ударение, то это **ПГ**.

Comment: @World - Сначала нужно выяснять, нет ли какого правила о паре корней, т.е. является ли рассматриваемая гласная **ЧГ**. Если нужного правила нет, пары корней нет, то подбираем однокоренное проверочное слово с гласной под ударением, это, выходит, у нас **ПГ**. Вот в **Задании 9** «вык..сил (траву)» — казалось бы, что это ЧГ, пара корней «кос/кас», но нет! Тут другой корень «кос», который с «кас» не чередуется, «кос/кас» – это про прикосновения, а «кос» – про скошенную траву и косых зайцев, именно об этом там по вашей ссылке и написано, в таблице в последней колонке >>>

Comment: @World - >>> в последней колонке приводятся «Похожие корни» — корни, которые только _похожи_ на корни с ЧГ, но на самом деле в этих похожих корнях ПГ, их надо проверять, подбирая _однокоренное_ проверочное слово с корневой гласной под ударением. Ведь если считать, что в слове «выкосил» ЧГ из пары «кас/кос», то выходит, что надо было бы писать _*кас**а**_, а не «коса (инструмент)», _*кас**а**рь_, а не «косарь (тот, кто косит траву)», так как после корня же идет **а**! Нет, в «вык..сил (траву)» корень не «кас/кос», тут ПГ: «кóсит».

Comment: @World - Насчет «изложение». «Изложение» вообще ничего не опровергает. Что ж тут такого особенного, что чередующуюся гласную кроме самогó правила о чередовании можно подтвердить _вдобавок ещё и_ проверкой ударением? Тут проверка ударением излишня, ведь мы же знаем, что корня *_лаж_ со значением «класть» не бывает. А вот с «выкосил» у нас выбора нет, проверка ударением — единственный способ узнать, какая тут гласная в корне, в этом слове **ПГ**. Ещё раз перечитайте _слова в последней колонке таблиц, эти слова **не подпадают под правила**, описанные в первых трёх колонках тех таблиц._

Comment: Я думал, что здесь тоже принято приводить собственные попытки решения. "Похожие корни" - это то, что я искал, спасибо, это решает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, в ответе на сайте ошибка. В слове «выкосить» гласная может чередоваться. Примеры: «скашивать», «выкашивать». Учитывая пары «растить»/«рост» и «пловец»/«плавать», все слова подходят, и этот вариант должен входить в число допустимых.

Comment: This exam uses specific terminology. Read the text by the link in the original post and comments to @YellowSky's answer.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was wrong: Russian being my native language, I don't know all of the rules :)